# How I can Place Image Buttons in Grid Format

Tags: android, android-layout

How I can arrange my android UI that contains 3 Image buttons in the below given format. I am new to android environment and my knowledge in the technology is zero. Please suggest me the best method to place the Image button in the below given format.

[image]

Comment: Is the yellow button under the other two buttons?

Comment: No Its like a grid. Consider like a button in the top and two button in the bottom

Comment: the height and the width are both 1:1？

Comment: Use RelativeLayout that would be best for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why you given the height 0dp. ?